# Dagger not generating Component classes for androidTest

Tags: android, android-testing, dagger-2, android-instrumentation, android-mvp

I am writing  testcase for androidTest using AndroidJUnitRunner.

I have added below dagger code snippet  in build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.4'
 annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.4'
```

//MockDemoApplication.java in androidTest folder

```
public class MockDemoApplication extends SampleApplication {

  @Override
  protected AppComponent createComponent() {
    return  DaggerTestAppComponent.builder()
            .mockAppModule(new MockAppModule())
            .build();
  }
}
```

But when I am trying to run testcase dagger is not generating classes for Component class and getting below error

```
Error:(9, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable DaggerTestAppComponent
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileStagingDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: Have you tried put androidTestCompile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$DAGGER_VERSION"?

Comment: yes, Its working now.

Answer (score 3):

Add androidTestCompile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$DAGGER_VERSION".

Comment: I have the same problem but adding androidTestCompile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$DAGGER_VERSION" does not solve the issue. Apart from the androidTests the DI setup is fine in the app.